# Replacing console font in qemu

Tags: qemu, bios

I'm experimenting with very old russian clone of cp/m86 operating system, trying to boot it in qemu. I've managed to boot the system, but unfortunately it rely on russian font being hardcoded in BIOS, so when it renders messages in console, they appear completely garbled (corresponding symbol in cp437 codetable is displayed). The messages are apparently rendered using standart int 10h BIOS interrupt.

I want to substitute font that BIOS use to render text with int 10h. I tried to recompile seaBIOS with modified font in vgasrc/vgafont.c, this didn't change anything.

I also tried to modify font bitmap in ui/vgafont.h in qemu source tree and to recompile qemu. This also doesn't help, it changes precisely nothing.

Any ideas where to look further?

Comment: In the QEMU source tree have you looked at `roms/vgabios/vgafonts.h` ?

Comment: Apparently the proper thing to do is to update roms/seabios/vgasrc/vgafont.c, and specifically to update vgafont16. I actually missed that there is more than one font in this file on the first look.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Would you like to make your comment into answer?  As it appears editing vgafont16 in roms/seabios/vgasrc/vgafont.c and then running 'make seavgabios' in roms/ resolved the issue.